# virtual function redefinition hides other overloaded functions of same name from another base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, function, overloading

Ok, I'm using virtual functions, overloaded functions, and multiple inheritance.  Of course this doesn't turn out well.

The scenario: Class `base1` has a virtual function that needs to be specified by its child.
Class `derived` derives from two parents `base1` and `base2`, and should use `base2`'s existing functionality to define `base1`'s virtual function.

This is ok, but awkward of course.  The motivation is I cannot change the class `base2` and the existing interface already heavily invested in has `base1` and `base2` class functions of the same name.  This is ok, nothing is implemented in `base1`, it should just redirect to `base2`.

My problem arises because `base2` has several overloaded functions of the same name as the virtual function in question.  All of the other overloaded versions become essentially hidden at compile time.

Here's a small demonstration code.

```
// this version does not compile, overloaded samenameFunc(int, int) cannot be found in the derived class.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base1 {
public:
    virtual void samenameFunc(int scratch) { cout << "from base1: " << scratch << std::endl; }
};

class base2 {
public:
    void samenameFunc(int scratch) { cout << "samenameFunc from base2: " << scratch << std::endl; }
    void samenameFunc(int scratch, int foo)  { cout << "samenameFunc(2 args) from base2: " << scratch << ", " << foo << std::endl; }
};

class derived : public base1, public base2 {
public:
    void samenameFunc(int scratch) { base2::samenameFunc(scratch); }// { cout << "from derived: " << scratch << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    derived d;

    d.samenameFunc(66);
    d.samenameFunc(77, 88);
    return 0;
}
```

And the compiler errors:

```
$ g++ inheritance_overload_tester.cc 
inheritance_overload_tester.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
inheritance_overload_tester.cc:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘derived::samenameFunc(int, int)’
inheritance_overload_tester.cc:18: note: candidates are: virtual void derived::samenameFunc(int)
```

If the overloaded `samenameFunc(int, int`) is renamed, I can compile and function as expected.  But remember, I can't actually change base2.

```
// this version does compile
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base1 {
public:
    virtual void samenameFunc(int scratch) { cout << "from base1: " << scratch << std::endl; }
};

class base2 {
public:
    void samenameFunc(int scratch) { cout << "samenameFunc from base2: " << scratch << std::endl; }
    void anotherFunc(int scratch, int foo)  { cout << "anotherFunc(2 args) from base2: " << scratch << ", " << foo << std::endl; }
};

class derived : public base1, public base2 {
public:
    void samenameFunc(int scratch) { base2::samenameFunc(scratch); }// { cout << "from derived: " << scratch << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    derived d;

    d.samenameFunc(66);
    d.anotherFunc(77, 88);
    return 0;
}
```

If this can't be fixed in the existing presentation, can someone suggest a different object inheritance model to solve my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the definition of the `derived` class, you can add a using declaration to make the function from `base2` visible:

```
using base2::samenameFunc;
```